# How to stretch children beyond max-width when wrapped (flexbox)

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a case where I'm required to use flexbox (and not css grid).

The parent can have multiple widths,
but the **children** should be:

- `100% width` IF they are wrapped
- `max-width 200px` IF they are not wrapped.

When the parent is eg. `300px`, I'm not sure how to achieve this. (Without JS)

Here's the codepen with the problem:
https://codepen.io/mesqueeb/pen/PMqoEa

[image]

Comment: consider media query

Comment: @TemaniAfif No I can't, because the parent div width is not related to the screen width. : S

Comment: CSS has no concept of wrapping. So child elements need something to tell them what to do when they wrap. That's where media queries or JS come in. More in the duplicate.

Comment: @Michael_B while I can see there is a similarity, it's not really a duplicate, because that question is more about the width of the children which is different depending on the contents. My case doesn't matter what the child items have inside of them, text or no text. I need the children to stretch to the width of the parent, unless if they fit on one line. But I guess the answer is "this is not possible".

Comment: Yes, but the child's behavior is tied to a wrap. And the parent container has no idea when its children wrap. That's why I felt the other post addressed this issue. However, feel free to vote to reopen if you disagree. And, yes, with CSS and no media queries, your layout is not possible, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @Michael_B That's ok, I guess I have my answer. :P Thanks for the insights either way!